# objectify filterkey with a partial key

Tags: java, objectify

I have an entity that has a parent.
I only know the child ID.

Here is the literal key of my entity

```
Key('LevelParent', '6092', 'Level', '3612')
```

So I only know "Level" and "3612".

I want request the nearest entity containing the child ID in its key.

I heard about this

```
ofy().load().filterKey(">=", startKey).filterKey("<", endKey)
```

but the thing is I  have no idea how to build the most accurate `startKey` and `endKey`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datastore does not support a query like "give me all the keys with a particular child key". You can go the other way 'round: Give me all the keys with a particular parent (ancestor), which is a simple index scan.

If you need a special subset of your data indexed, create explicit indexes.